# Many same objects in one form in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create one page with form to edit many objects.
I have product entity, product_details entity and product_details_list entity.
In details_list I have list of possible product properties
and there need to be form with all product_details. product_details entity has detail_id( from ), shortTxt and longTxt for each property. I'm doing so:

```
$this->details_list = $objectManager
          ->getRepository('Product\Entity\ProductDetailsList')
          ->findAll();
$form = new \ZfcAdmin\Form\ProductDetailsForm();

                    foreach($this->details_list as $detail) {
                            $form->add(array(
                                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
                                    'name' => 'shortTxt_'.$detail->getId(),
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'label' => 'short',
                                    ),
                                    'attributes'=> array(
                                            'id' => 'textareaId',
                                    ),
                            ));
                            $form->add(array(
                                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
                                    'name' => 'longTxt_'.$detail->getId(),
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'label' => 'long',
                                    ),
                                    'attributes'=> array(
                                            'id' => 'textareaIdLong',
                                    ),
                            ));
                    }
```

But how can i bind values from db to form and parse it after submit?
And I think I'm going the wrong way :(

Comment: Zend\Form has built-in support for collections within forms: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html